# Whitney Embedding theorem: Lee's lemma in Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds

As in the title. Here is Lee's proof:

[image]

And then "by applying the preceding lemma repeatedly, we can conclude that if an
n-manifold admits an injective immersion into some Euclidean space, then it ad-
mits one into $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$."

Wouldn't it be better just to define the relevant functions and go from there? Why use projective spaces and diagonals? I am self-studying this topic so there is probably something I am missing. Below I present my interpretation of this lemma and would like feedback. I am probably missing something important.

Let $i:M\to \mathbb R^N$ be inclusion. Define $f:M\times M\times \mathbb R\to  \mathbb R^N$ by $f(x, y, t) = t[i(x) -i(y)]$ and $di:T(M)\to  \mathbb R^N$ by $(x,v)\mapsto d_xi(v).$ Then, $0$ is in the image of both maps, and Sard's theorem implies that the set of vectors $v$ not in the image of $f$ or $di$ is dense in $\mathbb R^N:$ that is, since dim$(M\times M\times \mathbb R)=2n+1<N,\ d_{(x,y,t)}f$ is not surjective, for any $(x,y,t)$. Likewise, since dim $T(M)=2n<N$, the only regular values of $f$ and $di$ are those not in their range. Now applying Sard, we get that each image has measure zero in $\mathbb R^N$ so the complement is dense.

So, choose one such $v$ and let $H$ be the orthogonal complement of $v$ and $\pi_v$ the projection onto $H$. Then, $\pi_v\circ i$ is injective, for if not then $i(x)-i(y)=tv$ for some $0\neq t\in \mathbb R$, in which case $f(x,y,1/t)=v,$ which is a contradiction.

And $\pi_v\circ i$ is an immersion, for if not then there are $x\in M$ and and $0\neq w \in T_xM$ such that $d_x(\pi_v\circ i)(w) = \pi_v\circ d_xi(w)=0.$ This implies that $d_xi(w)=tv$ for some real number $t$. Now, $t\neq 0$ because $i$ is an immersion. But now we have a contradiction because $di\left (\frac{1}{t}w\right )=v.$

Edit: I think I (finally) understand Lee's proof: $\mathbb {RP}^{N-1}$ is the collection of hyperplanes through the origin in $\mathbb R$ and each one can be identified with a unit vector normal to it. Take such a hyperplane $P$ and let $\pi_P:M\to P$ be the orthogonal projection. (This corresponds to the vector $v$ in Prof Lee's proof). Now, if $p\neq q,$ then $\pi_P(p)=\pi_P(q)$ only if the $p-q$ is a vector perpendicular to $P$, so if we consider the smooth $f:M\times M\setminus \Delta\to \mathbb {RP}^{N-1}$ that sends $(p,q)$ to the hyperplane passing through the origin whose unit normal vector is $\frac{p-q}{\|p-q\|}$ then, by construction, the hyperplanes $P$ for which $\pi_P$ is injective lie in the complement of the image of $f$ and by Sard's Theorem, these are dense in $\mathbb {RP}^{N-1}$ and so the vectors $v$ that correspond to $P$ are dense in $\mathbb R^N$.

Now, if $(p,v)\in TM,$ then $d\pi_P(p,v)=0$ if and only if $v$ is a vector perpendicular to $P$ (using the same identification as the one  in Lee's proof) and so if we consider the smooth $g:TM\setminus M_0 \to \mathbb {RP}^{N-1}$, that sends $(p,v)$ to the hyperplane passing through the origin perpendicular to $v$ it follows again by construction and Sard, that the collection of $P$ such that $d\pi_P$ is imjective is dense in $\mathbb {RP}^{N-1}$ and so the collection of the corresponding vectors $v$ is dense in $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: It is a tough theorem.  Expect the proof to be "labored."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phrases like "... and using a dimensionality argument ..." raise eyebrows and doubts and skepticisms, so that's a gigantic problem with your proof.

Furthermore, given that you are working in $\mathbb R^N$ which has dimension $N$, rather than in $\mathbb R \mathbb P^{N-1}$ which has dimension $N-1$, I am not at all convinced that your unstated dimensionality argument will produce dimension bounds that are as tight as the ones given in Theorem 6.13. If you claim that they *will*, well... show me your dimensionality argument.

On top of all that, you have not even used the hypothesis $N > 2n+1$ in your proof, which should make those raised eyebrows go through the roof.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading too much into the OP's argument, but I took $N$ to implicitly satisfy $N > 2n+1$.  And the "dimensionality" argument is simply that $\dim TM < \dim domain(f) = 2n+1 < N$.  Doesn't this then give the same bound Lee gives?  (I agree that the OP should've provided the "dimensionality argument", given that he/she is saying another argument is not as good as it could be.)

Comment: @Lee Mosher  Yes, I have: since dim$(M \times M\times \mathbb R) = 2n + 1 < N,\ d_{(x,y,t)}f$ is not surjective, for any $(x,y,t)$. Likewise, since dim $T(M) = 2n< N$, the only regular values of $f$ and $di$ are those not in their range. Sard says that each image has measure zero in $\mathbb R^N$ so the complement is dense and the proof proceeds as I have outlined. If I made a mistake, I do not see where!

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, I used Lee's hypothesis, so I thought the "dimensionality argument" was obvious.

Comment: Then by all means put that dimension argument into your proof in place of the words "and using a dimension argument"; leaving it out can induce skepticism and misunderstanding. Leaving out motivation and intuition, as represented by Lee's first paragraph, can also introduce skepticism and misunderstanding. *You* may have understood this proof, and you can perhaps simplify it, but that does not mean that *others* who read it will understand it as well as you.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I still wonder why Lee used the maps $\kappa$ and $\tau$ though. That part of the proof was really what confused me at first, and led me to try to find other functions that worked as well. My confusion probably indicates a lack of math sophistication more than anything else. Sigh.

Comment: This doesn't indicate a lack of sophistication, nor any confusion on your part. I think you understand this theorem, and you are making it your own by formulating your own alternate details of the proof, which is the best way to understand mathematics. The point of my answer is that you have overlooked pedagogical reasons that may explain why that book's proof was written the way it was, particularly the opening paragraph.